# Click the button, save the data and go to next php page

Tags: php, database

I don't know what is the problem. After i click the button, it only the data into database but will not go to next php page. Help me find out what is problems. Thank you.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
$AddMCQ = "INSERT INTO tblmc(Name,FromDate,ToDate,Reason) VALUES('".strtoupper($_POST['txtName'])."','".$_POST['txtFrom']."','".$_POST['txtTo']."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtReason'])."')";
$AddMCResult = mysql_query($AddMCQ,$link);
header('Location: mcreport.php');

if($AddMCResult)
        echo "<script>alert('Record Added.');</script>";

}
//button
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. My guess is "output before header" ;) Edit: Oh, and add `exit;` after header, that might work; I said "might".

Comment: your javascript will never execute. Once you send the user to another page using `header();`, all the following code is not executed.

Comment: Got other easy ways without using header ??

Comment: There are a few. Ask the guys who've given answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
{

        $txtName=$_POST['txtName'];
        $txtFrom=$_POST['txtFrom'];
        $txtTo=$_POST['txtTo'];
        $txtReason=$_POST['txtReason'];
        $AddMCQ = "INSERT INTO tblmc(Name,FromDate,ToDate,Reason) VALUES('$txtName','$txtFrom','$txtTo','$txtReason')";
        $AddMCResult = mysql_query($AddMCQ,$link);
        if($AddMCResult)
        {
               echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
        echo "alert('Record Added.');\n";
        echo "window.location='mcreport.php'";
        echo "</script>";
        }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: `VALUES('$txtName','$txtFrom','$txtTo','$txtReason')` that will throw/cause an SQL error, since we're dealing with strings. you should have just used OP's code or omit it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

After your `header` put `die()` like

```
header('Location: mcreport.php');
die();
```

And better you use **Absolute** urls.Also you can use `exit()` instead of `die()`.

Comment: when i use redirect, it will appear this message "Fatal error: Call to undefined function redirect() in K:\xampp\htdocs\clinic\MakeMc.php on line 21"

Comment: Have you tries 2nd answer..?

Comment: it also no working...it appear this message "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at K:\xampp\htdocs\clinic\MakeMc.php:13) in K:\xampp\htdocs\clinic\MakeMc.php on line 21"

Answer (score 0):

Your "Problem" is the result in **$AddMCResult**

After your have use  **header('Location: mcreport.php');**

Your Script redirect to the given url and the result in $AddMCResult is not given any more

So a quick and dirty solution could be

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])){
$AddMCQ = "INSERT INTO tblmc(Name,FromDate,ToDate,Reason) VALUES('".strtoupper($_POST['txtName'])."','".$_POST['txtFrom']."','".$_POST['txtTo']."','".strtoupper($_POST['txtReason'])."')";
$AddMCResult = mysql_query($AddMCQ,$link);
$_SESSION['AddMCResult'] = $AddMCResult;
header('Location: mcreport.php');


}
```

AND on mcreport.php

> if(isset($_SESSION['AddMCResult']) && $AddMCResult)
>
> ```
>         echo "<script>alert('Record Added.');</script>";
> ```
>
> ...

But check, that session_start() was called on both files ...

Comment: it display error message somethings like this "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at K:\xampp\htdocs\clinic\MakeMc.php:13) in K:\xampp\htdocs\clinic\MakeMc.php on line 21"

Comment: The Problem .. you have generated any output **before** calling header()

Answer (score 0):

**Check Carefully Table Name and Passing Parameters - Through one to another page - see get and post method-**

```
<?php
include 'config.php';   
$submit="submit"; 
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sl_no=$_POST['sl-no'];
$f_name=$_POST['f_name'];
$l_name=$_POST['l_name'];

if($submit)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name(sl_no,f_name,l_name) values('$sl_no','$f_name','$l_name')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "Thank you! Information entered.\n";

}
else
{
echo "There Is Something Going Wrong While Insertion";
header('Location: error.php');
}
```

Comment: This `('$sl_no','$f_name','$l_name')` will fail, by the way. I know it's just an example, but it will nonetheless throw an SQL error because of values containing strings.